# How to use map() with data from axios response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object, axios

I'm using axios to get data from the server and storing it in the state. When I do `state.map( post => {console.log(post)} )`, I do not see anything.

I'm using `Express`, `Mongoose`, `NextJS` and `Axios`.

I'm using `axios` to get data from the server and storing it in `this.state.posts`. When I do `console.log(this.state.posts)` in `componentDidMount`, it logs the posts array perfectly. But when I do the same in 
`render(){ return ( /*here*/)}`
it does not show anything.

This logs all the posts without an error

```
async componentDidMount() {     
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/all')
        this.setState({posts: data, isLoading: false})
        console.log(this.state.posts)
    }
```

But this does not log anything -

```
render() {
  return({ 
    posts.map( post => {
      <Post title={post.title} />
    })  
  })
}
```

Comment: Try to wrap your jsx code with <React.Fragment>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{ 
   posts.map( post => {
    return <Post title={post.title} />
}) 
}
```

Maybe it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This single word had been haunting me since all day. But only to fix this error, I learned a lot of things today!

Answer (score 2):

You can provide callback to `setState` method which will run after the state is updated. You can use

`this.setState({posts: data, isLoading: false}, () => console.log(this.state.posts))`

to log updated state.

And in render method you should use

```
render() {
  return(
    this.state.posts.map( (post,i) => (
      <Post title={post.title} key={i} />
    ))  
  )
}
```

or

```
 render() {
  const { posts} = this.state;
   return(
      <React.Fragment>
       posts.map( (post,i) => (
        <Post title={post.title} key={i} />
       ))  
     </React.Fragment>
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
async componentDidMount() {     
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/all')
        this.setState({posts: data, isLoading: false}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.posts)
        return;
    })    
  }
```

Comment: I already tried it thinking its a problem about callbacks ! but the problem is fixed now and it was a silly mistake I wasn't returning the <Post /> in map()

Answer (score 1):

You need to return direclty `posts.map` with out opening `{}`

```
render() {
  const { posts = [] } = this.state
  return(
    posts.map( post => 
      <Post title={post.title} />
    )  
  )
}
```

`const { posts = [] }` will make sure that `posts` is an array and don't give you any errors like `cannot read .map of undefined`

Or you can open `{}` inside a `React.Fragment`

```
render() {
  const { posts = [] } = this.state
  return(
    <>
      { 
        posts.map( post => 
          <Post title={post.title} />
        )
      }
    </>    
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your render method like this:

```
render() {
  let Posts = {...this.state.posts};
  return({
    Posts.map( post => <Post title={post.title} />);  
  })
}
```

Your code is not correctly referencing the posts in state. Also,this way any operation on posts will not affect the state object directly. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
async componentDidMount(){

const res = await axios.get('/api/all')
  this.setState({
  post: res.data
  })
}
```

Comment: For a better answer try to add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
export default class Blog extends Component {
state = {post:[]}
componentDidMount() {
            // Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({post:response.data})
  // handle success
})
.catch(function (error) {
  // handle error
  console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
  // always executed
});
}render(){
const posts = this.state.post;
 const allposts = posts.map(post =>{
return( 
       <div>{post.title}</div>
 )
});
return(
<div>{allposts}</div>
);
}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).